# Check if the user has macros enabled

Tags: excel, vba

I only need to show a specific sheet when macros are disabled.

I leave photos and references of more or less what I locate to do.

[image]

Comment: This seems... circular. How would you do this in VBA when macros are disabled?

Comment: I've looked into this before. There is no way to check their settings.

Comment: And evaluate if the protected view is disabled or activated?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run any code if macros are disabled, they're *disabled* =)

What you *can* do, is show some "macros are disabled" sheet by default, and make sure the workbook is always saved with that sheet active.

Then in the `Workbook.Open` event handler (`Private Sub Workbook_Open` in `ThisWorkbook`), hide the "macros are disabled" sheet, and make the other ones visible.

Something like this (just for the concept - this is untested air-code), where `MacrosDisabledSheet` is the *code name* of your "macros are disabled! please enable macros to use this workbook" sheet - this should hide all sheets except the "macros are disabled" sheet on save, and then unhide all sheets (and hide the "macros are disabled" sheet) once macros are enabled, or when the workbook is opened with macros enabled:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'when opened with macros enabled, runs on open.
'when opened with macros disabled, runs when macros are enabled.
    ShowAllWorksheets
    ShowMacrosDisabledSheet hide:=True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave()
'always save with the "macros disabled" sheet active/visible
    ShowAllWorksheets hide:=True
    ShowMacrosDisabledSheet
End Sub

Private Sub ShowAllWorksheets(Optional ByVal hide As Boolean = False)
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not sheet Is MacrosDisabledSheet Then
            If hide Then
                If sheet.Visible <> xlSheetHidden Then sheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Else 
                If sheet.Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then sheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ShowMacrosDisabledSheet(Optional ByVal hide As Boolean = False)
    MacrosDisabledSheet.Visible = IIf(hide, xlSheetVeryHidden, xlSheetVisible)
End Sub
```

If you need the workbook to still be usable with macros disabled, then just keep in mind that the state of the workbook when you save it, will be the state it opens in - whether macros are enabled or not - so because you cannot know if the workbook will next be opened with macros enabled or disabled, you have to prepare the workbook to be in a "macros are disabled" state on save.

Answer (score 0):

Excel keeps its settings in the Windows registry. `Disable all with notification` | `Disable all except digitally signed macros` | `Disable all without notification` | `Enable all macros (not recommended)`, which once applied, will be translated into the values `2` | `3` | `4` | `1` for the `DWORD` value `VBAWarnings` under the hive:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\policies\microsoft\office\15.0\excel\security
```

where 15.0 stands for the Excel version installed on the system.

---

```
Value 1: Enable All macros
Value 2: Disable all macros with notification
Value 3: Disable all macros except those digitally signed
Value 4: Disable all without notification
```

---

You can use the following code in VBA to read and write the Windows registry keys:

```
'reads the value for the registry key i_RegKey
'if the key cannot be found, the return value is ""
Function RegKeyRead(i_RegKey As String) As String
Dim myWS As Object

  On Error Resume Next
  'access Windows scripting
  Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  'read key from registry
  RegKeyRead = myWS.RegRead(i_RegKey)
End Function

'sets the registry key i_RegKey to the
'value i_Value with type i_Type
'if i_Type is omitted, the value will be saved as string
'if i_RegKey wasn't found, a new registry key will be created

' change REG_DWORD to the correct key type
Sub RegKeySave(i_RegKey As String, _
               i_Value As String, _
      Optional i_Type As String = "REG_DWORD")
Dim myWS As Object

  'access Windows scripting
  Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  'write registry key
  myWS.RegWrite i_RegKey, i_Value, i_Type

End Sub

'returns True if the registry key i_RegKey was found
'and False if not
Function RegKeyExists(i_RegKey As String) As Boolean
Dim myWS As Object

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  'access Windows scripting
  Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  'try to read the registry key
  myWS.RegRead i_RegKey
  'key was found
  RegKeyExists = True
  Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
  'key was not found
  RegKeyExists = False
End Function
```

Comment: You have a logic problem here: If macros are disabled how can you run VBA code to change the registry keys? Right you can't ^^ Therfore it is impossible to use VBA to activate macros.

Comment: VBA macros are disabled per-application. So, if we automate another application we can do this check and enable them to be able to call an external VBA sub. I think it is helpful for others to know how it can be checked even in VBA!

Comment: But the OP wants to check if macros are enabled or not and accordingly show a specific sheet when macros are disabled. I don't see how this answers that question. I mean obviosly no one would start a Word file to check if Excel's macros are disabled. And if macros are disabled in Word too then it won't work anyway. That just moves the actual problem from Excel to Word.

Comment: Why not? You can re-start any external applications after enabling macros. And viola, you can call a VBA sub in Excel. Anyway, do you know how the OP is running a script?

Comment: *"Check if **the user** has macros enabled"* obviosly includes that this has to work in different computers under different conditions. Since the OP is very likely only providing the Excel workbook itself to his users and no additional scripts (anything else would not be very practicable) I definitely see no practical use here. • To your last question: If you suggest a VBA solution the user can only run it through any of the Office Apps that support VBA. As I said if you would run it in Word you have the same issue there if the Word has macros disabled.

Comment: `very likely` is the key thing here.